# (Proxy) Why does drilling down the hierachy with lazyloading in Entity Framework give different behavior?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, proxy, lazy-loading

**Clarification is needed about why Entity Framework behave differently in the following scenarios A and B.**

In these scenarios, the context remains alive, we use lazy loading and the following entities :

```
public class Root
{
    //... some Properties

    public virtual ICollection<Child> GoingDown { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    //... some Properties

    public virtual Root Root { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DeeperChild> GoingDeeper { get; set; }

}

public class DeeperChild
{
    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MoreDeeperTypeWithVirtualStuff> GoingFurtherDown { get; set; }
}
```

**Scenario A**

```
Root root = Context.Roots.First();
Console.WriteLine(root.GoingDown.FirstOrDefault().GetType().ToString());
//Display System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Child_[SomeGuid]
```

**Scenario B**

```
Root root = Context.Roots.First(r => r.Id == SomeId);
Console.WriteLine(root.GoingDown.FirstOrDefault().GetType().ToString());
//Display MyNamespace.Child
```

Since returned type isn't the "proxy" one, lazy loading doesn't work anymore in scenario B. Shouldn't it return the proxy type like the Scenario A does?

## EDIT:

**Problem isn't related to the scenario above**
After further research, it's appeared the different behaviour isn't related to the scenario but which root is fetched. In every case, the root loaded is of proxy type. When drilled down into childs, child's type is always proxy except for the specific root instance of scenario B. At this point in the code, that root is probably in EntityFramework's cache because that root is queried twice prior to that point (In two others class). These two others call doesn't fetch childs.

**New test have I made**
In the first fetch of the root instance I have added a dummy use of childs and there the child's type is proxy. However, even with the dummy use on the first call, child's type isn't proxy anymore when reaching seconds and thirds fetch.

Comment: I evaluated both scenario in break point in a method so same context is used for both scenario and there isn't other code between both scenario.

Comment: is there any query executed with just the Roots.First() call? if yes, what is it?

Comment: Can't repro your issue. And I can't think of anything that would cause different behavior in `First` with or without a predicate.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, I ended up with your conclusion, see my update on the question.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Yes there is queries prior to that point in time. The first fetch of root use some fields and also fetch another type of related sub-entities different than "Child".  When it's reach the second fetch, the problem is already there. There may be others queries that I'm unaware of since I didn't followed every step taken by the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was going on, there some code executed between first and second fetch of the root that flushed all childs and rec**reated brand new instance of them**. Thus, childs weren't coming from the database anymore, thus making them not the "proxy" type, thus making lazy loading not available for it.